# How can I bypass validates_email_format_of validation to save nil email value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In multiple places in a Rails 4 app, the validates_email_format_of gem is the perfect solution. But when an email address bounces, I'd like to save a nil value to the email field.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'validates_email_format_of', git: 'https://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of.git'
```

In my User model:

```
validates_email_format_of :email, :message => 'Email format looks invalid. Did you mistype?'
```

In my view:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete this Email Address', delete_email_addy_admin_path(user.id), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "btn_danger" %>
```

In the controller:

```
def delete_email_addy
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.email = nil
   @user.save!
   redirect_to email_bounces_admins_path
end
```

The result is that my message 'Email format looks invalid...' is produced. Using update_attributes instead of save or save! results in a rollback to the previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `allow_nil: true` is a simple handling for allowing `nil`s but I have a [`validation_skipper` gem](https://github.com/K-and-R/validation_skipper) that could handle more complex needs.

From my `Gemfile`:

```
# Rails gem that lets you skip validations
gem 'validation_skipper', '>= 1.3.0', github: 'K-and-R/validation_skipper'
```

Using this gem, you can have more complex logic around exactly when to skip validation.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [gem documentation](https://github.com/validates-email-format-of/validates_email_format_of), it supports both `:allow_nil` and `:allow_blank` options. So:

```rb
validates_email_format_of :email, 
                          :message => 'Email format looks invalid. Did you mistype?',
                          :allow_nil => true
```

**EDITED** to answer your follow-up

If you want to sometimes allow `nil` and sometimes not, it also supports `:if` and `:unless` options. You don't need the model to know anything about the controller (nor should you). You can just add a non-persistent boolean attribute to the Model and then use `:if/:unless` to check it.

**model**

```rb
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_email_validation

  validates_email_format_of :email, 
                            message: 'Email format looks invalid.',
                            unless: -> { skip_email_validation? }
  ...
end
```

**controller**

```rb
def delete_email_addy
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @user.email = nil
   @user.skip_email_validation = true
   @user.save!
   redirect_to email_bounces_admins_path
end
```

A quick look at @Karl's gem indicates that it automates the process of adding those non-persistent attributes. If you've got lots of cases where you need to conditionally skip validation and/or don't mind an additional gem, super, but for a single case it is probably just as easy to roll your own.

Comment: as you implied, in all other cases I don't want to permit a nil value. In the model I have been experimenting with "validates_email_format_of :email, :message => 'Email format looks invalid. Did you mistype?', unless: ..." but have not been able to make it work yet. Will the model know which controller_name and action_name is attempting to save a record?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can use:

```
validates_email_format_of :email,
    :message => 'Email format looks invalid. Did you mistype?',
    :allow_nil => true
```